# Eclipse error for localhost:6314

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

My eclipse always alert this message. I want to know why and how to solve it.

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Photon Milestone 6 (4.8.0M6)
Build id: 20180315-1217

Answer (score 2):

I think what's happening here is that you're doing a hot code replace; The frames on the stack do not match the what's running in your Virtual Machine.

I suggest you restart the debug session/target VM.

If this doesn't work, build your application and then launch it separately because it may be that your program is launching before finishing the build.

Comment: I think it may be the problem of JVM or JRE 9.0

Comment: try to fix the problem in the way i suggested and come back with feedback :).